# Как вызвать меню Андроида в котором выбирается сделать фото или загрузить из галереи?

Tags: java, android

Для работы с картинками в приложении нужно взять фото либо из галереи, либо сделать фото камерой. 
По отдельности все получается, т.е. созданы две кнопки, одна для вызова камеры, другая для вызова галереи.
А можно ли вызвать какое-то единое меню андроида, в котором будет этот выбор, чтобы оставить только одну кнопку?

Comment: Ну реализуйте DialogFragment и туда засуньте. Или Bottom Sheet

Comment: Хотелось бы использовать уже реализованные возможности, чтобы не изобретать велосипед.

Comment: https://github.com/ParkSangGwon/TedBottomPicker